# Short address attack in Solidity no longer possible?

Tags: security, ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to simulate all known attacks in Solidity for a research paper, presenting vulnerable smart contracts, tests to prove the vulnerability and the outputs with the successful attack results.

I've been attempting the **Short address vulnerability** (which I know it's not related to SCs, but to a lack of input validation at the presentation layer) but I have not been able to achieve this. Anytime I try, and I've passed the short address in many different ways (directly as a parameter, abi encoded, ...), it returns **"Error: invalid address (argument="address..."**.

I would like to know if Solidity has experimented any update which solved this issue and no wrong address is allowed anymore. I've been reading Solidity updates and EIPs but haven't found anything. If anyone knows about this, I would be very grateful for your help!

---

Answer (score 0):

Since solidity v0.5.0, it's impossible.
Please check the [changelog](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/v0.5.0/Changelog.md).

> Code Generator: Revert at runtime if calldata is too short or points
> out of bounds. This is done inside the ABI decoder and therefore also
> applies to abi.decode().